Is an autoencoder model encoder-only or encoder-decoder?
I'm writing up about different model architectures used in NLP, namely encoder-only models, encoder-decoder-only models, and have come across what seems to be a naming inconsistency. For decoder-only models it seems that they can be referred to as autoregressive models since they autoregressively predict the next token and encoder-decoder models can be referred to as sequence-to-sequence since they map a sequence of tokens to a different sequence of tokens.
However, I found various sources conflicting each other as to what an autoencoder is. While many sources claim that encoder-only models are autoencoders, others also refer to encoder-decoder models as being autoencoders.

You will find that the nomenclature in this field is not particularly rigorous. One of the main reasons I visit this site is to keep up with the new names professors (and others) are using for existing things.
That said, an autoencoder is comprised of an encoder, a latent space (some type of information choke point), and a decoder. Based on this and given the options you mention, a strong argument can be made that it is an encoder-decoder model, however it is not a sequence-to-sequence model at all. It is simply attempting to reconstruct the input, not predict a future value, token, or anything else.

Based on your explanation, you're indicating that an encoder-decoder model is not a sequence-to-sequence model. However, when you consider for instance machine translation which is a sequence-to-sequence task, this is often modelled using encoder-decoder models.

LSTMs and RNNs tend to be sequence to sequence encoder-decoder models. My point is that Autoencoders are encoder-decoder models but they are not used for sequence to sequence tasks.
